# Is there a way to react to a message on message create with hikari

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to create a bot that automatically reacts to certain users with the skull emoji because haha funny, and I've figured out how to send a message with the emoji but I would like to have the bot actually react.

This is what I have so far. Any advice?

```
async def benskull(event: hikari.GuildMessageCreateEvent):
    if event.author_id == [user id]:
        channel = event.channel_id
        msg = bot.rest.fetch_messages(channel)
        await bot.rest.add_reaction(channel, msg, ':skull:')
```

This is the error I got:
E 2022-10-06 10:46:28,990 hikari.event_manager: an exception occurred handling an event (GuildMessageCreateEvent)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\DrCreeperz\BensBot\bot.py", line 32, in benskull
await bot.rest.add_reaction(channel, msg, ':skull:')
File "c:\Users\DrCreeperz\BensBot\env\lib\site-packages\hikari\impl\rest.py", line 1612, in add_reaction
await self._request(route)
File "c:\Users\DrCreeperz\BensBot\env\lib\site-packages\hikari\impl\rest.py", line 817, in _request
await self._handle_error_response(response)
File "c:\Users\DrCreeperz\BensBot\env\lib\site-packages\hikari\impl\rest.py", line 839, in _handle_error_response
raise await net.generate_error_response(response)
hikari.errors.BadRequestError: Bad Request 400: (50035) 'Invalid Form Body' for https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/760186755323658270/messages/%3Chikari.impl.special_endpoints.MessageIterator%20object%20at%200x0000017556EA8770%3E/reactions/:skull:/@me

message_id:

- Value "<hikari.impl.special_endpoints.MessageIterator object at 0x0000017556EA8770>" is not snowflake.

Comment: You did not quite state what does not work in your example.  Please share more details of the error message you are getting, or what happens in general when you run your code.

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=react

Answer (score 0):

it should actually be:

```
await bot.rest.add_reaction(event.channel_id, event.message_id, emoji='')
```

this should fix your problem

to explain it, it doesn't need the ':skull:' since discord uses Unicode emojis, the only emojis that need that are custom emojis.